# Use component function in React loop

Tags: reactjs

I heard that () is not good at the rendering performance so it should not be used. However, in this case, it can not get the results when passing the function without ().

You can check the reseult in CodeSendbox: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/modern-silence-u1sft?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
const comp = () => {
  return <div>This is Component</div>;
};

const elements = [comp(), comp];  // Please Attention This Line!
const items = [];

for (const [index, value] of elements.entries()) {
  items.push(
    <div>
      {index}: {value} <br />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Index() {
  return <>{items}</>;
}
```

Result is:

```
0:
This is Component

1:
```

Why only `comp()` but not `comp`? What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: you are passing a executed function and function reference in an array `const elements = [comp(), comp];` why?

Comment: It's just an example of explaining. I think I have to use `comp` but it's not working. And I tried `comp()`, it returns what I want.

Comment: oh ok well then problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSX instead of calling the function:

```
const comp = () => {
  return <div>This is Component</div>;
};

const elements = [comp, comp];  // Remove the function call, save only the reference
const items = [];

// need to use Value with V instead of v for JSX
for (const [index, Value] of elements.entries()) {
  items.push(
    <div>
      {index}: <Value/> <br /> // render as JSX
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Index() {
  return <>{items}</>;
}
```

Here's a sandbox link showing how it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-mclean-7ymzr

Comment: It works! I tried <value /> but it not working. but your <Value /> is working! lol

Comment: @Centell React should components always start with a capital letter. https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#components

Answer (score 1):

`comp` is an arrow function that returns a JSX literal. It's a "function" that is stored in a variable called `comp`. When called/invoked as `comp()`, notice the parenthesis, it is executed and the computed return value is returned in the array. When used without the parenthesis, like `comp`, this is simply the reference to the variable (that can be invoked like a function).

Functions aren't valid react children nor valid JSX.

[Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

```
const comp = () => {
  return <div>This is Component</div>;
};

const elements = [comp(), comp];  // saves a JSX literal, and a function
const items = [];

for (const [index, value] of elements.entries()) {
  items.push(
    <div>
      {index}: {value} <br /> // trying to render a function here in `value`
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Index() {
  return <>{items}</>;
}
```

I assume you got the idea `()` is "not good at rendering performance" from some documentation about in-line anonymous arrow functions and event handlers and mapping an array of data. That is a different issue altogether. I believe your situation is just a misunderstanding about how arrow functions are invoked.

Comment: Thanks for your explain! My example code is the simplify but my real problem is more flexible. My real `comp` functions have some graphs and tables. There is no problem in this case..?

Comment: If calling them as functions (as expected) isn't causing any immediate issues then no, probably not a problem. React is generally performant and it isn't until you start generating **very** large virtualDOM trees and do bad anti-patterns that performance/optimizations may need to be looked at.